# Can you destroy a spider web on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, bugs

Can you destroy a spider web on shabbos if you simply do not want it around (you consider it unseemly)?

Comment: Is this a question about binyan/stirah or muktza?

Comment: `you consider it unseemly` Isn't this graf shel re'i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/756889/Dr.%20Harvey%20Babich/Spiders%20and%20webs:%20their%20halachos%20and%20biology

> Rabbi Yehoshua Neuwirth (1989) in section (23:9), “Housekeeping and
>   use of domestic facilities on Shabbos and Yom Tov,” codified the
>   following halachos. “Cobwebs on furniture or some other movable
>   article may be removed, provided that this is done not with one’s
>   hands, but with a broom or some other instrument. One should not
>   remove cobwebs from the walls, the ceiling, or any other part of the
>   home, both (1) because the cobwebs themselves are muktzeh and (2)
>   because doing so is analogous to the forbidden activity of detaching
>   something which is connected to the ground. If one finds a spider, one
>   is of course not allowed to kill it on Shabbath or Yom Tov.”
>   Apparently, the Sephardic viewpoint is slightly different, as Rabbi
>   Abraham HaCohen Soae (2005) noted the following: “It is permitted to
>   gently remove a spider web from the wall on Shabbat, provided one is
>   careful not to kill the spider on Shabbat. Other poskim forbid
>   removing a spider web on Shabbat because it is included in the
>   forbidden act of uprooting, tolesh min hamechubar.”