# Removing/destroying a spider web on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals, muktzeh, bugs

In response to the question, ["Can you destroy a spider web on Shabbos?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17413/can-you-destroy-a-spider-web-on-shabbos) asked on this website, part of the reply was a citation from Rabbi Yehoshua Neuwirth (1989) in section (23:9), “Housekeeping and use of domestic facilities on Shabbos and Yom Tov". Specifically he discusses spiderwebs on furniture and the walls of one's house.

On numerous occasions I have encountered spider webs on Shabbat on walkways to Shul or the entrance to my Sukkah.  Is there some way they be removed/destroyed if there is no easy alternative for passage?